# Eclipse AVD taking 30 min to launch?

Tags: eclipse, android-virtual-device, launch

So I've just started learning about Eclipse and know only the very basics. My AVD takes about 30 mins to launch. I googled the issue and found that taking even close to 2-3 mins is supposedly 'long' for the AVD to launch. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not even running the app now. After getting launched it displays the home screen and that's it.

Comment: What happen?...In my case it simply run...

Answer (score 1):

I had also face same problem initially but not as much time it required as you said(nearly 5 min) and I solve this by  changing priority.Priority = Processor time - so the higher priority means that process gets more time.

It can be done through
`Task Manager -> processes -> emulator-arm.exe (right click) -> set priority to above normal` or High .(I have do this in window 7)

You can also change the loading time of emulator by increasing device Ram size.For more detail follow link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

Comment: Did that. The home screen was displayed on the AVD a few mins later and it said that my app has stopped working.